# How does Improved Critical feat work with a Soul Knife's Emulate Weapon Blade Skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics

How does [Improved Critical](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat/) feat work with a Soul Knife's [Emulate Melee Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Emulate_Melee_Weapon) Blade Skill?

For intents and purposes "Emulate Weapon" functions like the weapon emulated, from damage to damage type and critical threat range and so on. So let say I emulate a rapier.

Now I want to take the Improved Critical feat, but the feat is weapon specific. So when I pick the Improved Critical feat, do I choose the Mind Blade or the rapier to apply the feat to, or can the feat apply to the Mind Blade no matter what weapon it the Emulate Melee Weapon Blade Skill emulates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can take Improved Critical Mind Blade (*or rapier*)

From Form [Mind Blade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#Form_Mind_Blade_Su),

> She can also choose her mind blade for feats requiring a specific weapon choice, such as Weapon Focus and Improved Critical.

And Emulate Melee Weapon,

> The soulknife **is proficient with her mind blade in this form** and it functions in all ways as the chosen weapon.

The emulated melee weapon 'counts as' whatever weapon you Emulate and, if you chose them, Feats and other abilities that specify that weapon would work... but it is *also* still a Mind Blade and benefits from anything that specifically affect Mind Blades.